# Assign values from a for loop into an array list of integers

Tags: java, arrays

For this stage of my code I am attempting to print a 8x8 grid of numbers randomly ranging from 1-8. I am struggling to assign the values in the fill arraylist to the random numbers in the two for loops. How do I solve this.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;   // for Arraylist
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
public class Game {
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
        int b1 ,b2 ,b3 ,b4 ,b5 ,b6 ,b7 ,b8;
        int c1 ,c2 ,c3 ,c4 ,c5 ,c6 ,c7 ,c8;
        int d1 ,d2 ,d3 ,d4 ,d5 ,d6 ,d7 ,d8;
        int e1 ,e2 ,e3 ,e4 ,e5 ,e6 ,e7 ,e8;
        int f1 ,f2 ,f3 ,f4 ,f5 ,f6 ,f7 ,f8;
        int g1 ,g2 ,g3 ,g4 ,g5 ,g6 ,g7 ,g8;
        int h1 ,h2 ,h3 ,h4 ,h5 ,h6 ,h7 ,h8;
    public int fill(ArrayList<Integer>ar) {
        gui();
        int[] space = new int[] {a1, a2 ,a3 ,a4 ,a5 ,a6 ,a7 ,a8 ,
                                     b1 ,b2 ,b3 ,b4 ,b5 ,b6 ,b7 ,b8 ,
                                     c1 ,c2 ,c3 ,c4 ,c5 ,c6 ,c7 ,c8 ,
                                     d1 ,d2 ,d3 ,d4 ,d5 ,d6 ,d7 ,d8 ,
                                     e1 ,e2 ,e3 ,e4 ,e5 ,e6 ,e7 ,e8 ,
                                     f1 ,f2 ,f3 ,f4 ,f5 ,f6 ,f7 ,f8 ,
                                     g1 ,g2 ,g3 ,g4 ,g5 ,g6 ,g7 ,g8 ,
                                     h1 ,h2 ,h3 ,h4 ,h5 ,h6 ,h7 ,h8 }; }
public void gui()
 {System.out.println(a1+" "+a2+" "+a3+" "+a4+" "+a5+" "+a6+" "+a7+" "+a8);
  System.out.println(b1+" "+b2+" "+b3+" "+b4+" "+b5+" "+b6+" "+b7+" "+b8);
  System.out.println(c1+" "+c2+" "+c3+" "+c4+" "+c5+" "+c6+" "+c7+" "+c8);
  System.out.println(d1+" "+d2+" "+d3+" "+d4+" "+d5+" "+d6+" "+d7+" "+d8);
  System.out.println(e1+" "+e2+" "+e3+" "+e4+" "+e5+" "+e6+" "+e7+" "+e8);
  System.out.println(f1+" "+f2+" "+f3+" "+f4+" "+f5+" "+f6+" "+f7+" "+f8);
  System.out.println(g1+" "+g2+" "+g3+" "+g4+" "+g5+" "+g6+" "+g7+" "+g8);
  System.out.println(h1+" "+h2+" "+h3+" "+h4+" "+h5+" "+h6+" "+h7+" "+h8);
}
public  double num(ArrayList<String>ar){
int[] randomNumbers = new int[64];
 for (int index = 0; index < ar.size(); index++)
     {
         randomNumbers[ index ] = (int) ( Math.random()*8 );
         }
         for (int index = 0; index < ar.size(); index++)
     {
         randomNumbers[ index ] = (int) ( Math.random()*8 );
         randomNumbers[ index ] =  system.out.println(space[index++]);
        }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You've declared the `fill` array as a local variable in `fill` - so its scope is limited to that method. Perhaps you meant to declare it as a field? (As an aside, I don't think that declaring 64 separate variables is a good idea at all... I'd suggest *just* having a matrix...)

Comment: This code does not compile. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Yes, the code wont compile past end of the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your int[] space array is declared inside your fill method, and as such is not in scope outside of that method.

If you would like it to be in scope, consider declaring int[] space as a field of your class, which if you like can be initialized in your fill method.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @MatthewRomano See where you've written "public class Game {", insert a line below that "int[] space;". That declares 'space' to be a field of your Game class. Then in the fill method you can remove the "int[]" from before "space" since otherwise you would be declaring space twice. 

Beware however that space will remain uninitialized until after fill is called.

Comment: I have made these changes and now the error reads "incompatible types: void cannot be covered to int" It still highlights the "System.out.println(space[index++]); }"

Comment: Sounds like it thinks index is void (and is trying to cast it to an int to read from the space array). Are you still declaring index to be an int in the for loop declaration?